# Using two different fonts for links?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm creating a website for my final project in HTML. I am using two different web fonts that I downloaded. One is used for the links at the top of my pages (linked to other web pages of the final) and the second font is basically used for the everything else on each page. I am using an external style sheet (a requirement for the project) and in that style sheet, it specifies the font I want used for links. The issue is, I want to create links on the bottom of one of my pages that don't use that same font, but instead use a different one, while still keeping the same font on the links at the top of the page.

This is the top of my web page, I want the links here to be in this font

[image]

This is the bottom of the same web page, and I want the links down here to have a font that matches the text to the left of Font Freak

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example how you can assign font styles to different elements,

```css
body
{
font-family: 'Gothic A1', sans-serif;
}

a
{
text-decoration:none;
}

.another
{
color: #262626;
font-family: 'Do Hyeon', sans-serif !important;
}

.desired
{
color: #c69145;
font-family: 'Gugi', cursive !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gothic+A1" rel="stylesheet"> 

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Do+Hyeon" rel="stylesheet"> 

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gugi" rel="stylesheet"> 

This is deault font used in css for body
<hr>
<a href="#nothing">Nothing</a>

<br><Br>
This is specified font for a class used inside anchor tag
<hr>
<a href="#something" class="another">Something</a>

<br><br>
For more fonts just create another class and write your desired css in it with font-family .
<hr>
<a href="#desired" class="desired">Desired</a>
```

Comment: Thank you! That helped me out a lot!